# Determine the order of each element od $D_\square$. Determine all subgroups of $D_\square$.

Tags: group-theory

> Determine the order of each element od $D_\square$. Determine all subgroups of $D_\square$.

$$_2^1\square_3^4\longrightarrow  _1^4\square_2^3\longrightarrow \theta=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 
4 & 1 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$$
and $$\theta^2=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 
3 & 4 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}\\\theta^3=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 
2 & 3 & 4 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\\\Delta=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 
4 & 3 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\\\Delta\circ \theta=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 
3 & 2 & 1 & 4
\end{pmatrix}\\\Delta\circ \theta^2=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 
2 & 1 & 4 & 3
\end{pmatrix}\\ \Delta\circ\theta^3=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 
1 & 4 & 3 & 2
\end{pmatrix}\\ e=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 &4
\end{pmatrix}\\\Longrightarrow D_\square=\{e, \theta, \theta^2,\theta^3, \Delta, \Delta\circ\theta, \Delta\circ\theta^2,\Delta\circ\theta^3   \}$$

Have found the order of each element, but do not know find quatindade existing subgroups, and which are the same ... Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma**: If there are  $n$ elements of order $d$ in a group $G$, then there are $\dfrac{n}{\phi(d)}$ cyclic subgroup of order $d$ where $\phi$ is Euler-phi function.

By above lemma we can easily count the cyclic subgroups. Since, there are $5$ elements in order $2$ and $2$ elements in order $4$, we have $5$ cyclic subgroup of order $2$ and $1$ cyclic subgroup of order $4$.

Now, we need to count noncyclic ones. Notice that such a subgroup must have order $4$ or $8$.

You can see that $D_8=<\theta,\Delta>$ as you construct.

$$H_1=<\theta^2,\Delta>\cong Z_2\times Z_2$$
$$H_2=<\theta^2,\Delta \theta> \cong Z_2\times Z_2 $$

are the subgroup of order $4$. (you should check it by computation )